# Ruby - How to extract public, rsa private and CA keys from .pfx file on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have a certificate in .pfx format and I need to extract the Public, Private and CA certificates using ruby.

Using the shell I can make it this way:

```
# Extract Public Key (ask for password)
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out file_public.pem -clcerts -nokeys

# Extract Certificate Authority Key (ask for password)
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out file_ca.pem -cacerts -nokeys

# Extract Private Key (ask for password)
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out file_private.pem -nocerts -nodes

# Extract RSA Private Key from private .pem
openssl rsa -in file_private.pem -out file_private_rsa.key

# Create Combo file with Public and RSA Private Keys
cat file_private_rsa.key file_public.pem > file_combo.pem
```

[On this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589722/openssl-equivalent-command-in-ruby) DMKE shows how to transform the keys to .PFX, but how to do the other way round?

Answer (score 9):

```
pkcs = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read("xyz.p12"), "password_for_xyz.p12")
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pkcs.key.to_pem)
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pkcs.certificate.to_pem)
```

Comment: Thanks! This one really helped me out

Answer (score 4):

```
pkcs = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read("file.pfx"), "password")

pkcs.key.to_pem

pkcs.certificate.to_pem
```